# How to get the IP that others can use to connect to my socket build in c++

Tags: c++, tcp, ip

My computer is using Wi-Fi provided by a tplink router.

I am using a website to get my IP, https://www.whatismyip.com.

My code is fine, because I can connect to the socket in my own computer by using 127.0.0.1.

Here is my code from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-cc/amp/

But I don't know why my friend can't connect to my socket using the IP I get from the website.

I wonder, do I need to set up something in my router, or am I using the wrong code?

Comment: It sounds like you need to set up your networking to direct internet traffic to your PC from your router. You can google "port forwarding", that may provide an answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you get from whatismyip.com is your public IP address. Your computer is probably behind a NAT/PAT (Network Address Translation / Port Address Translation), meaning your machine has a private IP address that gets translated by your router/firewall into the public one displayed by whatismyip.com

You have two solutions:

1. Get a public IP address from your Internet provider, and disable NAT on your router (probably you'll need help for this).
2. Configure port forwarding on your router so that it forwards traffic on your public IP address to a given port on your machine.

Comment: #2 is the way to go. And if the router supports uPnP, your software can configure the port forwarding in code when it creates the listening socket. Otherwise, you have to configure the router manually